# WordPress 4.8.1 uses mysql_connect which doesn't work with PHP 7

Tags: wpdb

I just upgraded to PHP 7 only to find that WordPress 4.8.1 (latest version) still uses mysql_connect in the wp-db.php module, but mysql_connect has been deprecated.

The following code is taken from wp-db-php, lines 1567-1571:

```
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    $this->dbh = mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
} else {
    $this->dbh = @mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this>dbpassword,
                                 $new_link, $client_flags);
}
```

Here is the output when I try to run my program:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in D:\ApacheHtdocs\ConneXions\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1570  
>   Stack trace:  
>   #0 D:\ApacheHtdocs\ConneXions\wp-includes\wp-db.php(658): wpdb->db_connect() 
>   #1 D:\ApacheHtdocs\ConneXions\wp-includes\load.php(404): wpdb->__construct('root', '', 'connexions', 'localhost') 
>   #2 D:\ApacheHtdocs\ConneXions\wp-settings.php(106): require_wp_db() 
>   #3 D:\ApacheHtdocs\ConneXions\wp-config.php(104): require_once('D:\ApacheHtdocs...') 
>   #4 D:\ApacheHtdocs\ConneXions\wp-load.php(37): require_once('D:\ApacheHtdocs...') 
>   #5 D:\ApacheHtdocs\ConneXions\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('D:\ApacheHtdocs...') 
>   #6 D:\ApacheHtdocs\ConneXions\index.php(17): require('D:\ApacheHtdocs...') 
>   #7 {main} thrown in D:\ApacheHtdocs\ConneXions\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1570

I can't believe that WordPress says it recommends PHP 7, but it doesn't work with it. What am I missing here?

Comment: `mysql_connect` is only used as a fallback when `mysqli` is not detected. It would appear you have neither `mysqli` or `mysql` installed ( `mysqli` is recommended, `mysql` is deprecated )

Answer (score 10):

This sounds like you do not have [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) installed and/or enabled on your server. IIRC `mysqli` was added to php in version 5.5, and the older `mysql` extension had been deprecated and fully retired since then. If you upgraded from a very old PHP version it might be that you still need the extra step of enabling `mysqli`.

(wordpress checks for the existence of `mysqli` and only if it does not exist tries the older `mysql` functions.)

Comment: [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) was part of PHP in versions 4 & 5, and removed in version 7. [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) was introduced in PHP 5.0.0 and works in all PHP 5 versions and so far in all PHP 7 versions. You're probably thinking that mysql was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0.

Comment: @CJDennis, that ia exactly what I said regarding the deprecation. If you think there is a mistake in my english, you are more then welcome to edit the answer ;)

Comment: I was correcting your thought that mysqli was introduced in 5.5.0, when it was introduced in 5.0.0.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @MarkKaplun answer, I post some code from the wpdb class:

Here's how the `wpdb::use_mysqli` is determined:

It's initalized with:

```
/**
 * Whether to use mysqli over mysql.
 *
 * @since 3.9.0
 * @access private
 * @var bool
 */
private $use_mysqli = false;
```

and then in the `wpdb` constructor we have:

```
/* Use ext/mysqli if it exists and:
 *  - WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL is defined as false, or
 *  - We are a development version of WordPress, or
 *  - We are running PHP 5.5 or greater, or
 *  - ext/mysql is not loaded.
 */
if ( function_exists( 'mysqli_connect' ) ) {
        if ( defined( 'WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL' ) ) {
                $this->use_mysqli = ! WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL;
        } elseif ( version_compare( phpversion(), '5.5', '>=' ) || ! function_exists( 'mysql_connect' ) ) {
                $this->use_mysqli = true;
        } elseif ( false !== strpos( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '-' ) ) {
                $this->use_mysqli = true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you should do to solve this problem, is to edit your php.ini file.

run where is `php.ini`
I found mine at:

`/etc/php/php.ini` (although I don't know what OS you are running simple find yours)

Look for these two files:

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=mysqli.so
```

and uncomment them. 
Voila, that would get the job done anytime.

Further reading:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PHP

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Xamppp 7.x for Windows?

It happened to me when I upgraded my Xampp 5.6 to Xampp 7.1. Inspecting the configuration file **C:\Xampp\php\php.ini**, I noticed a lot of errors involving the name of PHP extensions (they lack the prefix php_ and the suffix .dll). One of them is related to mysqli.

The wrong setting I found there:

```
extension=mysqli
```

The right setting (after editing this line):

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Correcting that solved my problem.

By the way: don't forget to correct all other wrong settings (the correct name of the extensions can be seen at C:\xampp\php\ext).